# How to stream non-exhaustive list of clips into rtmp server using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

I have program that generates clips uniform length ( around  seconds ) continuously. Clips are named chronologically (DT stamp). Now I need to merge those clip and stream all of them in real time via ffmpeg.

I prefer FFmpeg, but any other option is also welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: concat filter may help

Comment: concat is useful when we have finite number of clips. In my case, clips are being generated in realtime by a python script

Comment: I know ffmpeg can take "raw input" in from the stdin (i.e. frames like yuv420p or its like). GL!